# Can't get access to my Dropbox account from php in linux

Tags: php, linux, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-php

I was download dropbox-php-sdk. Ok
Next, I write script on php:

```
<?php
require_once "dropbox-sdk-php-1.1.6/lib/Dropbox/autoload.php";

use \Dropbox as dbx;

$dropbox_config = array(
    'key'    => 'fasgsasgas',
    'secret' => 'gasawggasg'
);

$appInfo = dbx\AppInfo::loadFromJson($dropbox_config);
$webAuth = new dbx\WebAuthNoRedirect($appInfo, "PHP-Example/1.0");

$authorizeUrl = $webAuth->start();
echo "1. Go to: " . $authorizeUrl . "<br>";
echo "2. Click \"Allow\" (you might have to log in first).<br>";
echo "3. Copy the authorization code and insert it into $authCode.<br>";

$authCode = trim('eadasfafasfasfasfffffasfasfsafsafsafsafsafafa');

list($accessToken, $dropboxUserId) = $webAuth->finish($authCode);
echo "Access Token: " . $accessToken . "<br>";

$dbxClient = new dbx\Client($accessToken, "PHP-Example/1.0");

$accountInfo = $dbxClient->getAccountInfo();
print_r($accountInfo);
?>
```

When, I run this script, I have output:

```
root@iredmail:/var/www/test.tl# php test2.php
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'The Dropbox SDK requires the cURL PHP extension, but it looks like you don't have it (couldn't find function "curl_init").  Library: "/var/www/test.tl/dropbox-sdk-php-1.1.6/lib/Dropbox/RequestUtil.php".' in /var/www/test.tl/dropbox-sdk-php-1.1.6/lib/Dropbox/RequestUtil.php:5
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/test.tl/dropbox-sdk-php-1.1.6/lib/Dropbox/autoload.php(27): require_once()
#1 [internal function]: Dropbox\autoload('Dropbox\Request...')
#2 /var/www/test.tl/dropbox-sdk-php-1.1.6/lib/Dropbox/WebAuthBase.php(14): spl_autoload_call('Dropbox\Request...')
#3 /var/www/test.tl/dropbox-sdk-php-1.1.6/lib/Dropbox/WebAuthNoRedirect.php(56): Dropbox\WebAuthBase->_getAuthorizeUrl(NULL, NULL)
#4 /var/www/test.tl/test2.php(14): Dropbox\WebAuthNoRedirect->start()
#5 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/test.tl/dropbox-sdk-php-1.1.6/lib/Dropbox/RequestUtil.php on line 5
```

Where, I have error? I need to get account information. But I can't understand, where I have error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the exception says, you do not have the PHP cURL extension installed.

Depending on your linux distro, the command may be different, a quick google for "install php curl [distro]" will get you an answer.

If your distro uses apt-get use the following:

`sudo apt-get install php5-curl`

Don't forget to restart apache.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the cURL extension installed in order to use the Dropbox SDK... As per the exception.

> The Dropbox SDK requires the cURL PHP extension, but it looks like you don't have it